# Add class to svelte component

Tags: svelte

I created two components:

**1. btn.svelte**

```
<button class="btn" />
```

**2. btnHold.svelte**

```
<script>
    import Btn from './btn.svelte';
</script>
```

I'm trying to add a new class `btn--hold` to `btn.svelte`

```
<Btn class="{btn} btn--hold" />
```

I get an error on `class`.

Basically I would like in the end to have:

```
<button class="btn btn--hold" />
```

How can I add a class to an imported component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`class` is protected keyword, you can work around that by changing the name like this:

```html
<script>
    // ...
    let className = '';
    export { className as class };
</script>

<button class="btn {className}" ...
```

Usage example (`btn` class is already added internally):

```html
<Btn class="btn--hold" ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working perfectly.
Let me ask you one more thing, how can I add some text into that component like:
<button>text</button>
`<Btn class="btn-hold" text />`

Comment: Just define another property and interpolate it or use a slot. Have you done [the tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/declaring-props)?

Answer (score 4):

In the `btn.svelte` component you can do:

```html
<button class={ 'Btn ' + ($$restProps.class ?? '') } />
```

- The `$$restProps` variable is an object of attributes which were passed to the component, but not explitly declared as props via the `export let` keyword.
- I used the nullish coalescing operator `??`, because if you don't pass the `class` attribute to the component, the result will be `Btn undefined`.

Now, in the `btnHold.svelte` component you simply do:

```html
<Btn class="btn--hold" />
```

Working REPL here: https://svelte.dev/repl/c2b6625ed73144eeb6bebce6ea4a4d82?version=3.58.0

Comment: Are there any gotchas with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by exporting a `className` variable from the component, and adding it onto the button's existing class

1. btn.svelte

```
<script>
    export let className;
</script>

<button class="btn {className}" />
```

2. btnHold.svelte

```
<script>
    import Btn from './btn.svelte';
</script>

<Btn class="btn--hold" />
```

to add the btn--hold class to the button.

Comment: As H.B. pointed out in a previous answer, 'class' a reserved keyword in Javascript so Svelte complier is going to give you an error if you try this. You'll need to use 'className' or some other appropriate identifier for your use case.